Publish target in an SDK style WiX5 project doesn't work?
I have a similar problem as this Post
I have a WiX 5 Setup Project UserInterfaceSetup.wixproj that is intended to install my WPF-Razor Project with Project file UserInterface.csproj and Publish Settings in FolderProfile.pubxml.
Even with the Attribute Publish="true" in the ProjectReference Element of UserInterfaceSetup.wixproj, the UserInterface Project is not published when build the WiX 5 Setup Project.
When I first publish manually the UserInterface Project and then Build the WiX 5 project, then everything runs well.
Ho to have the UserInterface published automatically when building the WiX 5 Setup UserInterfaceSetup Project?
Content of UserInterface.csproj
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <RootNamespace>CTE.HR.SmartSensorPairing.UserInterface</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>CTE.HR.SmartSensorPairing.UserInterface</AssemblyName>
    <ApplicationIcon>wwwroot\img\paired.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <PublishProfile>FolderProfile</PublishProfile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="NewFolder\**" />
    <Content Remove="NewFolder\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="NewFolder\**" />
    <None Remove="NewFolder\**" />
    <Page Remove="NewFolder\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="nlog.config" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="GitVersion.MsBuild" Version="5.12.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Wpf" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="8.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MiniValidation" Version="0.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="5.2.8" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Core\Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Resources\Resource.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resource.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Resources\__Resources.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>__Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\img\paired.ico">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\Resource.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resource.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\__Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>__Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="nlog.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Content of FolderProfile.pubxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121.
-->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>x64</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\x64\Release\publish\</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <_TargetId>Folder</_TargetId>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Content of UserInterfaceSetup.wixproj
 <Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/5.0.0">
  <ItemGroup>
    <BindPath Include="..\..\src\UserInterface\bin\x64\$(Configuration)\Publish">
      <BindName>BinPublishPath</BindName>
    </BindPath>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="img\Branding Setup.png" />
    <Content Include="img\Branding Setup_58.png" />
    <Content Include="img\CTE_Setup.ico" />
    <Content Include="ReadMe.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.UI.wixext" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\UserInterface\UserInterface.csproj" Publish="true" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Content of Package.wxs
    <Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
      xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui">

    <?define Titel = "Test Setup"?>
    <?define ProductName = "XYZ.UserInterface"?>
    <?define ProductManufacturer = "XYZ" ?>
    <?define DirectoryCompany = "$(var.ProductManufacturer)" ?>
    <?define DirectoryProduct = "$(var.ProductName)" ?>

    <Package
        Name="$(var.Titel)"
        Manufacturer="XYZ"
        Version="!(bind.FileVersion.MainExeFile)"
        UpgradeCode="ba1b4010-0adf-4dbb-bb86-60b4c1c5c618"
        Compressed="yes">

        <SummaryInformation Manufacturer="XYZ" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />


        <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="img\Branding Setup_58.png"/>
        <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="img\Branding Setup.png"/>

  
        <Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="img\CTE_Setup.ico"/>
        <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon.ico" />



        <Feature Id="Main" Title="$(var.ProductName)">
            <ComponentGroupRef  Id ="AllMyFiles"/>
            <ComponentRef Id ="ExeFiles"/>
         </Feature>


        <ui:WixUI Id="WixUI_InstallDir_NoLicence" InstallDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"/>



    </Package>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="AllMyFiles" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Files Include="!(bindpath.BinPublishPath)\**">
                <Exclude Files="!(bindpath.BinPublishPath)\$(var.ProductName).exe" />
                <!-- Hier entfernen weil er schon unter MainExeFile integriert ist-->
                <Exclude Files="!(bindpath.BinPublishPath)\appsettings.json" />
            </Files>
            <Component NeverOverwrite="yes" Permanent="yes">
                <File Source="!(bindpath.BinPublishPath)\appsettings.json" />
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
        <Component Id="ExeFiles" Guid="F13F59E5-B2AB-4676-B9E1-20A219EFBAAD"  Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <File Id="MainExeFile" Source="!(bindpath.BinPublishPath)\$(var.ProductName).exe"/>
        </Component>
    </Fragment>


    <Fragment>

        <StandardDirectory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" >
            <Directory Id="XYZ" Name="XYZ"/>
        </StandardDirectory>
        <StandardDirectory Id="ProgramFiles6432Folder">
            <Directory Id="CompanyFolder" Name="$(var.DirectoryCompany)">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.DirectoryProduct)" />
            </Directory>
        </StandardDirectory>
    </Fragment>
 
</Wix>

Any help or support will be greatly appreciated.

Doesn't anyone here have any ideas or advice? I would be so grateful.
